# JQuery Form Injection Not Appearing in Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having a problem where I am using JQuery to add input into form after it has created. The initial form looks like this:

```
<form class="purchase-product" >
<div id="purchase_quantity_discounts"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1" id="label" >
<input type"button" name "submitme" id="product-quantity-button"></button>
</form>
```

And the JQuery for appending

```
$('#purchase_quantity_discounts').append('Quanity: </strong> <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" value="1" />');
```

Now I am trying to get the quanity:

```
$('#' + purchase_page).on('click', '#product-quantity-button', function() {
  var formData = Utilities.parseForm(".purchase-product");
  var amount = formData.quantity;
  var product_id = formData.product_id;

  alert(amount);
  alert(product_id);

});
```

So the product_id always shows but the quantity never comes up. WHy is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Added Inputs Not Being Read On Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692846/jquery-added-inputs-not-being-read-on-submit)

Answer (score 2):

Your append is missing the closing `>` for the input, see:

```
('#purchase_quantity_discounts')
    .append('Quanity: </strong> <input type="text" name="quantity"
        placeholder="Enter Quantity" value="1" /'); //> needed before the ')
```

Comment: Thats a mistake is my posting and does not solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm okay, try wrapping your entire `append` into a <div>, the markup still looks a little off :)

Comment: No that is still not it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `id`s to your inputs and getting the values that way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there are several typos in your example code. Have a look at this jsFiddle that works.

Not sure of that form-parsing utility you're using `Utilities.parseForm`, but I've recreated the functionality with jQuery

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pavsaund/Pt2R2/2/